# Relaxed ordering modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I am going thought the C++ 11 memory model/ordering   standard for revision purposes .
For std::memory_order::relaxed there is the following example

```
// Thread 1:
r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // A
x.store(r1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // B
// Thread 2:
r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // C 
y.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed); // D
```

And the following statement

> is allowed to produce r1 == r2 == 42 because, although A is
> sequenced-before B within thread 1 and C is sequenced before D within
> thread 2, nothing prevents D from appearing before A in the
> modification order of y, and B from appearing before C in the
> modification order of x. The side-effect of D on y could be visible to
> the load A in thread 1 while the side effect of B on x could be
> visible to the load C in thread 2. In particular, this may occur if D
> is completed before C in thread 2, either due to compiler reordering
> or at runtime.

In need some further explanation on this.
In thread 1 reordering cannot take place since there is a dependency between load in variable r1 and in store in vx. Is this right?

In thread 2 reordering can happen since there is no dependency between and write. Am I correct?
Is this problem fixed with the model acquire release? If yes why? Using acquire release model reordering is prevented but if thread 2 for example executed faster than thread 1 y keep value 42, after that in thread 1 x will be 42 as well. What am I missing

Comment: Yes, acquire/release would make sure the y.store(42) doesn't become visible to other threads until after x.load has happened.

Comment: But in thread 1, ISO C++ doesn't forbid value-prediction for loads, which could hypothetically allow reordering in thread 1. But in practice CPUs don't do that, and wouldn't make a still-speculative value visible outside the current thread. And even ISO C++ says implementations *shouldn't* allow out-of-thin-air values to magically materialize, so in other cases that does put limits on value-prediction (if they could formally disallow it, they would). See [Preventing of Out of Thin Air values with a memory barrier in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51232730) re: a similar litmus test to yours.

Comment: But x.load happens before y.store.What am I missing?Do you mean y.load()

Comment: On real compiler and CPUs that can't do weird stuff in thread 1, the key effect here is compile-time or run-time reordering in thread 2 such that `y=42` is visible to thread 1 before `r2=x` takes a value.  `r2 = x.load(acquire)` or `y.store(42, release)` would prevent that in practice.  Formally, there's no synchronizes-with / happens-before unless an acquire load sees the value from a release store, so we'd also have to change thread 1 to make this safe.  As current written, `x.load` is sequenced-before `y.store` in thread2, but they don't have an inter-thread happens-before ordering.

Comment: Just to clarify things because I am confused. Based on standard since x.load happens it is an acquire.No reordering before this.After y.store happens. At this point release is take place on y2. What is the value of y? Thread 1 let 'assume that still is not running

Comment: `x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` is not an acquire operation.  The memory order you used is `relaxed`, which is weaker than `acquire`.  There is no `y2` in your program.  After `y.store` executes, `42` is the latest value in the modification-order of `y`.  It's not a `release` operation unless you change the source for that, too.  Later loads of `y` from this thread will see `42`, and same for other threads after some finite / reasonable amount of time (two different clauses in the standard say store values *should* be visible to loads after finite time, or a reasonable amount of time.)

Comment: Yes my question is if change this to acquire release model and for example put a sleep in thread 1 what is final value in y and x

Comment: The final value of `y` is always `42`, there's only one store to it and the value is constant.  The final value of `x` is either `42` or its initial value, depending on which thread ran first.  If the sleep in thread 1 is before the `y.load`, then most likely it will see `42`.  The value in `r2` can't be `42`; that's the change from `relaxed` and the interesting part of this litmus test.

Comment: @getsoubl A sleep will only *sometimes* help, but is never guaranteed to, as "reasonable amount of time" is not quantified in the standard.  Generally you should not rely on "waiting time" for values to propagate this way between threads if you want to maintain invariant: rather, the "finite" or "reasonable" time is intended to allow you to know it won't take literally forever.  And in practice, if you try to rely on that for ordering, you'll almost certainly run into other problems.